# using apache location directive to list folders from trac

Tags: apache, installation, location, trac

I have the following directory structure:

```
--var
----trac
------company1
--------project1
--------project2
------company2
--------project3
--------project4
```

and i was wondering if theres a way to specify in httpd.conf to list the directories when i go to domain.com/trac. Currently i wrote:

```
<Location /trac>
    Options Indexes
</Location>
```

But i dont know how to specify the document root to /var/trac.
I tried to do

```
PythonOption TracEnvParentDir "/var/trac"
PythonOption TracUriRoot "/trac
```

but i get error 500, and i believe that is because the folders in /var/trac are not trac environments.

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're right. You need to find a way to let Apache handle requests to "/" without the help of Python and trac.

It's a bit hard to give you advice because I don't know what your httpd.conf looks right now, but my trac-setup used a `<LocationMatch>` directive to catch everything that should not be handled by trac so Apache can take care of it.

So you could do something like this:

```
<LocationMatch "^/trac/.+">
    # Your trac directives here
    PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend
    ....
</Location>

Alias /trac "/var/trac"
<Directory "/var/trac">
    Options Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```